# Rails remote form complete handler fires but success/failure don't

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, remote-forms

I am submitting a form through rails, and the response is coming backing with 200 OK headers.  My complete event fires, but neither success nor failure fire.  Any ideas?

The JS:

```
$('form#booking-email').bind('ajax:complete',function(){
    alert('complete');

});

$('form#booking-email').bind('ajax:success',function(){
    alert('success');
});

$('form#booking-email').bind('ajax:failure',function(){
    alert('failure');

});
```

My Controller

```
 respond_to do |format|
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
```

The Response:

```
Status: 200 OK

Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Length: 1

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Date: Sat, 03 Nov 2012 01:00:11 GMT

Etag: "7215ee9c7d9dc229d2921a40e899ec5f"

Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2012-02-14)

Set-Cookie: _myeasybnb_session=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJWQ3NTE2ODMzZjMyY2RhZTU1NjAwMzk3MWIyYjdhZDMzBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMTFNN1hvWGhUdytSSjVRcCtrdWFLVTk5NnBEQWF5QXVxRlR2L1pwV1JjUmM9BjsARkkiGXdhcmRlbi51c2VyLnVzZXIua2V5BjsAVFsISSIJVXNlcgY7AEZbBmkGSSIiJDJhJDEwJEJ3Uy5lTzI3Ly4xY05xWlhGZzJ3cy4GOwBU--bd4de54c468e9cedc322949bba91adb5a60bb92f; path=/; HttpOnly

X-Request-Id: 0bb75d4727fbe149b868214f39763030

X-Runtime: 2.183082

X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with differents web browsers. I had some similar problems with jQuery and one browser. Or try with the status value, not with `:success`.

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    200: function() {
      alert('success');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using the complete function and doing an if/else based on the status.  Hackish and dumb, but hey, it works.